# React global objects & events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm new to React and still having some trouble "thinking in react" when it comes to global events & scope.

My goal is to maintain some global data about the "session" like whether a user is logged-in and their identity.

**My main container looks like this:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Header from './Header';
import Routes from "./Routes";

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="parent-container">
                <Header />
                <Content />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class Content extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="content" >
                <Routes />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

`<Header />` is simply a nav bar with a title & links.

`<Routes />` is a `react-router` which looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import HomeView from "../presentational/_Views/HomeView";
import LoginView from "../presentational/_Views/LoginView";
import CreateUserView from "../presentational/_Views/CreateUserView";
import TestView from "../presentational/_Views/TestView";

const Routes = () => (
    <div>                
        <Route exact path="/" component={HomeView} />
        <Route path="/login" component={LoginView} />
        <Route path="/test" component={TestView} />
        <Route path="/create" component={CreateUserView} />
    </div>
)

export default Routes;
```

Each route loads a "presentational" view component that contains child components for that particular view (Login view component imports a LoginForm component etc).

Whenever my app is hard-loaded (or reloaded) I would like the following logic to be fired (pseudo-code):

```
if session_token exists:
    - make a call to API
    - verify session
    - store a global session object containing session data
```

I figured I can do something like this in a `componentWillMount()` function on the `App` component...

```
//...
class App extends Component {
    componentWillMount(){
        if(token && valid(token)){
            // store the user session in an object containing token, user-role, etc.
        }
    }

    render() {
//....
```

..but this seems like a bad design.

The other part to this is to:

1. show/hide navbar links based on whether a user is logged in (show "login" link if not logged in, show "log out" link is logged in)
2. check authentication on state change before the view is rendered.

The above two is where I wanna go for context but focusing only on the main issue here just to wrap my head around it.

How is something like this done "the React way"?

Comment: dont use componentWillMount , at least use UNSAFE_componentWillMount() it will be depricated in react 17    check this out https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount

Comment: I dont want to use either if its in bad or unsafe practice

Comment: for use Authentication i guess you should use react router auth https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow

Comment: I'm having a dilemma like this as well. But this doesnt seem like something you'd want each component dealing with separately (i could be wrong though). I was thinking about having some application state with MobX or Redux that would manage some isLoggedIn state, which would only be true if the login request was successful. and that way any of my components could subscribe to that state and render differently based on that.

Comment: @MattPengelly that's what I was thinking as well but is it necessary to use something like Redux to establish a state for React to "subscribe" to? shouldn't it be possible to simply store some data in a global scope that's available to the entire application without having to explicitly pass it to every component?

Comment: I would think it should be doable, though honestly im not entirely sure how. I'll be watching this post to see if you find an answer :)